# Couldn't integrate a CSS file into my project

Tags: python, html, css, django, href

I would like to connect my **layout.html** file with a CSS file so that every other page extending my **layout.html** has access to this CSS file.

That is the code:

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Aufgabenzettel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/aufgabenzettel/static/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Meine Aufgaben</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**main.css**

```
h1 {
    color: aqua;
}
```

The href in **layout.html** is probably correct bacause I can be redirected to it in VS via ctrl + click. However, the h1 in **index.html** still appears in black instead of aqua...
What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate every kind of help!

Comment: look at your source in browser to see where it is looking for the css file. You probably want to be using something like  `{% static "css/main" %}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ but my guess is your css call is getting a 404.

Comment: @AMG My browser says *Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/aufgabenzettel/static/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.*

Comment: @AMG Otherwise, if I try it with `href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" ` I get the following error: *Invalid block tag on line 5: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?*

Comment: Hello @mellomax9 you have to put `{% load static %}` at top of your code so it loads static function for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add `{% load static  %}` at the top of your code where you want to use `static` function in template and than you have to use static function like this `{% static 'your_css_path_inside_static_directory' %}` eg.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Aufgabenzettel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/aufgabenzettel/static/css/main.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution. It worked once but thereafter changes in the main.css don't seem to have any influence on the html files. The aqua colour for h1 was applied but remains present and I can't change it... Do you have any idea how it could be solved?